# How to implement Android app with in-app subscription model

Tags: android, google-play

I'm currently trying to implement an app that is free to download, and the user must pay for 30 days worth of access at a time.

I've searched around for quite a while, and everything indicates that this isn't currently supported using the in-app billing service. If this is true, what are my options? I would like something that does not violate the Android store's TOS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question a while back, so I'll answer it in case anyone has the same question.

The subscription feature was announced on the 24th of May on the Android developers blog: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/in-app-subscriptions-in-google-play.html

Answer (score 0):

To confirm, you would in fact use the In App Billing service from Google, which would be compliant with their TOS.  Using an external payment process would not be compliant, or selling real goods (only virtual goods can be sold with IAB).

You can only use Google's IAB to not run afoul of their TOS.

Answer (score 0):

google recently added subscription to in-app billing.

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_subscriptions.html

Comment: Thanks, I discovered this as soon as it was announced.